# Check tag for content with Overwrite warning

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc

```
void device_DeviceArrived(ProximityDevice sender)
    {
        //Compatible Device enters area
        if (stance == WriteStage.PREP)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Writestages won");
            //Perhaps here
            updateStatusRectangle(Colors.Yellow);
            stance = WriteStage.WRITING;
            updateStatusText("Writing...");
            writeToTag(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            updateReceivedText("Device connected!");
        }
    }

private void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Handler ran");
        var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
        var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);
        foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Record type: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Type, 0, record.Type.Length));
            var specType = record.CheckSpecializedType(false);
            if (specType == typeof(NdefTextRecord))
            {
                var textrec = new NdefTextRecord(record);
                updateReceivedText(textrec.Text);
            }

        }
    }
```

The above event and handler are executed when the phone comes into contact with an NFC device. For intents and purposes in this app, I need to ensure that before writing to a card, if it already has content, it will prompt the user to verify overwriting the data. I commented where I think it should go, but as far as checking for the Message, I'm not sure how to go about it. I can't call the handler without the ProximityMessage, and I don't know of another way to view the message.

The Question: Is it possible to call the MessageReceivedHandler (or check the message at all), from device_DeviceArrived? 
(Note: Debug.Writelines are for test purposes, and this is just a quick NFC writer I'm throwing together).

**UPDATE: In attempting to find a work around, I ran into a different problem.**

```
public bool promptUserForOverwrite()
    {
        bool response = false;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBoxResult cc = MessageBox.Show("You are about to overwrite data.  Proceed?", "Overwrite?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (cc == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MessageBox OK result");
                    response = true;
                }
            });
        return response;
    }

private void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Handler ran");
        var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
        var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);
        foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Record type: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Type, 0, record.Type.Length));
            var specType = record.CheckSpecializedType(false);
            if (specType == typeof(NdefTextRecord))
            {
                var textrec = new NdefTextRecord(record);
                updateReceivedText(textrec.Text);
            }
        }
        bool pow = promptUserForOverwrite();

        if (!pow)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Prompt returned");
            //This always hits - pow is always false. 
        }

        if (stance == WriteStage.WRITING && pow)
        {
            //writeToTag(msg);
        }
    }
```

This would work as a work around; the problem is the beginInvoke method. I need it for cross thread access, but used like this seems to make it run at a later time (when the thread is free?). The bool pow is always false, even after I click ok on the messagebox (debugged, and it does get the result, but after I can no longer use it). Is there an alternative that I can use for the Dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but I have this working. You need to get a TaskScheduler from the UI thread, so declare a

```
private TaskScheduler sched;
```

and then on the OnLoaded event for the page

```
sched = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Then your methods

```
public async Task<bool> promptUserForOverwrite()
{    
    return false;   
}

private async void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Handler ran");
    var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
    var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);
    foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Record type: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Type, 0, record.Type.Length));
        var specType = record.CheckSpecializedType(false);
        if (specType == typeof(NdefTextRecord))
        {
            var textrec = new NdefTextRecord(record);
            updateReceivedText(textrec.Text);
        }
    }


    var task = promptUserForOverwrite();

    var pow = await task.ContinueWith(t =>
    { 
            MessageBoxResult cc = MessageBox.Show("You are about to overwrite data.  Proceed?", "Overwrite?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (cc == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MessageBox OK result");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, sched);

    if (!pow)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Prompt returned");
        //This always hits - pow is always false. 
    }

    if (stance == WriteStage.WRITING && pow)
    {
        //writeToTag(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried it with async/await, though not this implementation. Regardless, the problem persists; when executing, it seems to skip over the pow declaration in the handler, and only run the dispatcher when the handler is done.

Comment: This looks like it will work as needed, but for some reason it doesn't work. I implemented it, but got a System.AggregateException. During debugging, the problem continues: it appears to skip over the ContinueWith method (checking the value in the debugger for pow in the if statements says that the pow.Result was not yet computed. Is it running at a different time?

Comment: When I transcribed I forgot to add the await. Change line to

     var pow = await task.ContinueWith(t =>

Comment: Once changed, the exception unwrapped (AggregateException), and new exceptions (TaskCanceled, NullPointer(?))bubbled up. Unsure of where to go from here; I may stay around this approach, but I think it may be time for another work around.